# Storing a destructuring map for later use

Tags: dictionary, clojure, destructuring

I've been trying to get this to work with quote, quote-splicing, eval, and whatever else I can think of, but no luck so far. I understand why it doesn't work - it's being seen as a map, and it's trying to eval `a`, `b`, and `c` - just not how to get around it.

```
(def destructor {a :a b :b c :c})
; CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context, compiling:(:1:15)

(let [destructor my-map]
  'etc)
```

I have a rather involved destructuring map that I'm considering using several times, so it seemed a good idea to tuck it away somewhere. Maybe there are better ways to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good idea, but you can't do it in quite this way, because the thing you want to store is not really a value, so you can't store it in a var.

Instead, you can define a macro that includes this in its expansion:

```
(defmacro with-abc [abc & body]
  `(let [~'{:keys [a b c]} ~abc]
     ~@body))

(with-abc foo
  (...use a, b, and c...))
```

Comment: The funny-looking `~'` in the let-clause is so that a, b, and c don't get namespace-qualified by the syntax-quote. I think it's necessary, but I'm not at a real computer right now, so if someone sees that it's not feel free to edit.

Comment: Very nice. I can't use `:keys` (good to see it as an example, though), as I have "a rather involved destructuring map" (i.e. of many levels), but swapping in my map works great. I was playing with using a macro for a bit, but - despite having succeeded with them many times - I guess I still don't have my head completely around passing everything in and getting a whole new, fully transformed thing back yet. Thanks!

Comment: @amalloy: For the record, you're right -- the `~'` is necessary. I tested it, and it works as-is, but taking out the `~'` causes a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't let qualified name: user/a`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like @amalloy's answer was my first instinct too and it's probably the way to go. That said, it might be worth considering a plain ol' higher-order function:

```
(defn destruct
  [{a :a b :b c :c} f]
  (f a b c))

(destruct my-map
          (fn [a b c]
            (println a)
            (println b)
            (println c)))
```

It's a little nosier and you're forced to name the bindings every time, but you avoid potential hygiene issues and, depending on your level of comfort with metaprogramming, it's a little easier to put together.

Comment: Yeah, I want to avoid naming things, as my map not only contains dozens of things, but they're also at several different nesting levels. It's good to try to find the functional route, though, where possible. Thanks.

Comment: Gotcha. Sounds like the macro's the way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to quote the destructing pattern

```
(def my-destructor '{a :a b :b c :c})
```

You can do this with levels of quoting/unquoting, but it is easier to see with a little helper function.

```
(defn- with-destructor* [binding & body] 
  `(let ~binding ~@body))
```

This `eval` occurs at "compile" time (during macro expansion)

```
(defmacro with-destructor [[destructor form] & body] 
  (eval `(with-destructor* [~destructor '~form] '~@body)))
```

As shown

```
(macroexpand-1 '(with-destructor [my-destructor {:a 1 :c 3}] (+ a c)))
;=> (clojure.core/let [{a :a, b :b, c :c} {:a 1, :c 3}] (+ a c))
```

Result

```
(with-destructor [my-destructor {:a 1 :c 3}] (+ a c))
;=> 4
```

Comment: The definition of `with-destructor` has no reason to use `eval` at all. Its body should just be `(apply with-destructor* [destructor form] body)`. And of course you can avoid that `apply` if you drop the varargs from `with-destructor*` (as, in my opinion, you should).

Comment: @amalloy Perhaps I'm missing something, but I believe your suggestion would work only with a literal destructor expression as in `(with-destructor [{a :a b :b c :c} {:a 1 :c 3}] (+ a c))`, but not one stored in a var as in the question.

Comment: I see. You're trying to let the `destructor` be supplied by the user, not fixed for a particular macro. I was confused because you named the macro argument the same as the var, and I thought the macro was referring to the var.